# What's the best practice/guideline to display a "please wait" message in Android?

Tags: android, xamarin.android

I have an app where an action by the user sometimes causes the app to get data from the server before it can be displayed, like getting detail info for an item (the info is too large to preload it for all items) or refreshing all data.

While this is in process i don't want the user to do anything else. What is the guideline to display a "please wait" message? Ideally it should be possible for the user to cancel the request if he wants to.

I can do it with an alert dialog, but the operation usually takes just half a second to a second, and imo it looks really strange for an alert dialog to pop up just for a moment, maybe not even long enough to be able to read the message.

Another option i see is the snack bar, but it doesn't prevent the user from doing anything else or navigate away.

Is there a guideline or best practice what to do in this scenario?

I'm using Xamarin.Android, but i don't think that matters.

Comment: Are you asking about "how to code" or "what should be displayed"?

Comment: "what should be displayed" and if possible which classes represent the corresponding UI element. I can probably figure out the details of "how to code", and if not i'll make a new question, but this is really about "what should be displayed"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can show a loading circle in place where the content being loaded will be displayed like [this](https://material-design.storage.googleapis.com/publish/material_v_8/material_ext_publish/0B14F_FSUCc01N2kzc1hlaFR5WlU/061101_Circular_Sheet_xhdpi_005.webm). When it finishes, replace the loading circle with the content.

Actually "i don't want the user to do anything else" is not acceptable in most Android design patterns. Android app should allow the user to take control of the app.

About canceling the request, you can add a cancel button near the loading circle, or add a cross inside the circle which will stop the process when being pressed. The latter is preferred.

For more patterns see [this](https://material.google.com/components/progress-activity.html#progress-activity-types-of-indicators).

**About progress dialog**

As far as I know, progress dialog which block the user interaction is discouraged in the new Android. But I am sorry that I cannot find the reference yet, maybe somewhere in Material Design guidelines document. However, because you are the developer, it's all up to you :D.

Comment: He is not asking for the widgets/views but a best way to display progress bar whenever there is any long running task!

Comment: Yes, I explain the best way to display. He asked about the guideline, and I provide the link. Why downvoted? :/

Comment: Actually i like this approach for at least a part of my cases. Now i get the data from the net, and then open a new activity. It's probably better to open the new activity, empty with just a spinner and then display the charts and stuff when the data is ready. For the complete data refresh (which also throws the user back to the entry point/home screen of the app) i'll probably use a ProgressDialog.

Answer (score 0):

Check out the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) on `AsyncTask`.

I would do the long running task in an `AsyncTask`, show a `ProgressDialog` in it's `onPreExecute` method and hide it after it finised, in `onPostExecute`.

To prevent the user from closing the dialog you can use the `Dialog.setCancelable()` method.

You can define a custom layout for your `Dialog` and set it via the `setContentView()` method.